# Compile Boost libraries with MSVC-11 targeting a 64bit architecture

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I need to compile `Boost Libraries 1.53` in order to use them with Visual Studio 2012.

So far I tried this way:

```
.\boostrap
.\bjam.exe --toolset=msvc-11.0 --address-model=64
```

The compilation process terminate without any problem, but when I try to compile a Visual Studio Project which depends on that libraries I get the following error:

```
>libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib(thread.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

Can you give me some hint on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `toolset` and `address-model` are features, not options, so they should not be preceded with `--`. Try `bjam.exe toolset=msvc-11.0 address-model=64`.